# Why do we need to pass the gradient parameter to the backward function in PyTorch?

Tags: pytorch

According to the docs, when we call the backward function to the tensor if the tensor is non-scalar (i.e. its data has more than one element) and requires gradient, the function additionally requires specifying **gradient**.

```py
import torch
a = torch.tensor([10.,10.],requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([20.,20.],requires_grad=True)

F = a * b
F.backward(gradient=torch.tensor([1.,1.])) 

print(a.grad)
```

`Output: tensor([20., 20.])`

Now scaling the external gradient:

```py
a = torch.tensor([10.,10.],requires_grad=True)
b = torch.tensor([20.,20.],requires_grad=True)

F = a * b
F.backward(gradient=torch.tensor([2.,2.])) #modified

print(a.grad)
```

`Output: tensor([40., 40.])`

So, passing the **gradient** argument to backward seems to scale the gradients.
Also, by default `F.backward()` is `F.backward(gradient=torch.Tensor([1.]))`

Apart from scaling the grad value how does the `gradient` parameter passed to the backward function helps to compute the derivatives when we have a non-scalar tensor?
Why can't PyTorch calculate the derivative implicitly without asking explicit gradient parameter as it did for the scalar tensor?

Answer (score 1):

It's because PyTorch is calculating the jacobian product. In case of scalar value, `.backward()` w/o parameters is equivalent to `.backward(torch.tensor(1.0))`.

That's why you need to provide the tensor with which you want to calculate the product. Read more about [automatic differentiation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/autogradqs_tutorial.html#optional-reading-tensor-gradients-and-jacobian-products).